# How to get a transfer out form from NOW Pensions

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

My old employer chose NOW Pensions as the auto-enrole pension (despite a 1.2 star rating on trustpilot.com) and now I want to transfer the money accrued in that account to my current pension. I've tried for a while to find a transfer out form on their website and have sent a message to them asking for one, but there's been silence on their end. I'm wondering if anyone knows where to get one?

Comment: The pension transfers I've done previously have all been initiated from the *target* - tell your new provider the details of the current pension, and they *should* handle it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was operating off the basis of doing a transfer out form from my teacher's pension which I also had to do recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In my experience*, pension transfers are handled by the *target* provider. Here is an example - [transferring to the Hargreaves Lansdown SIPP](https://www.hl.co.uk/pensions/transfer-to-the-vantage-sipp):

> ## How to transfer
>
> We don’t charge anything to transfer to us. But it’s a good idea to
>   check if your provider charges exit fees, or if you’ll lose any
>   benefits or guarantees.
>
> Here's how transferring works:
>
> 1. You apply to transfer
> 2. We contact your provider and start the transfer
> 3. We keep you updated with progress
> 4. We tell you when everything arrives
> 5. When you’re ready, you start investing

And here's another: [the AJBell YouInvest SIPP](https://www.youinvest.co.uk/transferring-to-us):

> ## How to transfer
>
> 1. You'll need to open a SIPP with us if you don't have one already. This takes less than 10 minutes, and you can do it online.
> 2. During the application, you'll be asked to enter the details of the account(s) you want to transfer. We may also need you to post us some
>      documentation.
> 3. Already have a SIPP with us? You can start the transfer process by logging in and from the 'My account' menu, choosing 'Transfers', then
>      'SIPP'.
>
> That's it. We'll handle the rest of the admin from there and let you
>   know when the transfer is complete.

As the transfer process goes through, you should receive communications from the old provider informing you what's happening, as an anti-fraud measure. But you shouldn't need to deal with them any further yourself.

---

Note that this straightforward process applies to defined *contribution* pensions *only* - for *defined benefit* schemes (aka 'final salary'), such as your "teacher's pension" quite possibly was, there may be quirks, which both the above providers gloss over more or less:

> ## Types of pensions you can transfer
>
> You can transfer most types of pension to the HL SIPP:
>
> (list of DC pension types)
>
> If you have a final salary pension or another pension type not listed
>   above, please give us a call on 0117 980 9926 and we may be able to
>   help you transfer.

(HL)

> ## What to check before transferring
>
> You can easily transfer most types of UK pensions to us – even
>   pensions you've already started taking an income from. But before you
>   decide to transfer yours, it’s important you do the following:
>
> ...
>
> Consider talking to a suitably qualified financial adviser about
>   whether transferring to a SIPP is right for you. If you have a final
>   salary pension worth at least £30,000, you have to seek financial
>   advice before transferring it

(AJBell)

Years of mis-selling scandals have left UK financial services providers (rightly) paranoid about even *allowing* their clients to make poor decisions, so they would be very wary about accepting a transfer out of a scheme with any guarantees or side-benefits.

However, all auto-enrollment schemes are Defined Contributions, so in your particualar case right now there shouldn't be a problem.